# Function returning undefined with nested readFile function, discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wrote a function that should return a date from a JSON file based on the user's id but I'm getting `undefined`. When I place the `readFile` function inside the `messageCreate` event listener, it works. It just doesn't work when the code is placed in a function.

Here's the js

```
function GetDate(userid) {
  fs.readFile("users.json", "utf-8", (err, jsonString) => {
    if(err) {
      return err;
    } else {
      try {
        const obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        let date = "";
        for (i=0; i < obj.users.length; i++) {
          if(obj.users[i].id === userid){
            date = obj.users[i].date;
          }
        }
        return date;
      }
      catch {
        return "Error parsing JSON!" + err;
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Here's the `messageCreate` event listener that calls the function.

```
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if(message.content === "test") {
    const date = GetDate(message.author.id);
    console.log(date);
  }
})
```

Here's the JSON file

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "1010101010",
      "date": 1671876850
    },
    {
      "id": "2020202020",
      "date": 1671451250
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `GetDate` doesn't return anything - there is no `return` statement inside it, only in the nested callback function, which is ignored anyway. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) may be helpful for you to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return anything from `GetDate`. You return inside a callback function only.

If you want to use callbacks, you will need to pass a callback function to `getDate` and call that function once you get the results (or an error).

Check out the code below. I've also simplified that `for` loop a bit.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
// ...
function getDate(userid, callback) {
  fs.readFile('./src/users.json', 'utf-8', (err, jsonString) => {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    try {
      const obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
      for (let user of obj.users) {
        if (user.id === userid) {
          return callback(null, user.date);
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return callback('Error parsing JSON!' + err);
    }
  });
}

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.content === 'test') {
    // date is only available inside the callback function
    getDate(message.author.id, (date) => {
      console.log(date);
    });
  }
});
```

You could also use promises though. This makes your code more readable:

```js
const { readFile } = require('fs/promises');
// ...
async function getDate(userid) {
  try {
    const data = await readFile('./src/users.json', 'utf-8');
    const obj = JSON.parse(data);
    for (let user of obj.users) {
      if (user.id === userid) {
        return user.date;
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.content === 'test') {
    const date = await getDate(message.author.id);
    console.log({ date });
  }
});
```

Comment: Just a question, under "date is only available inside the callback function", does that mean for me to use the date value I should call it inside the date function? Is it possible to call it outside?

Comment: It is possible if you use the second snippet with the promises.

Comment: I see. Thanks. So if I have a block of code that would make use of the date value, I would wrap it around the date callback function that is passed to GetDate. I seem to get it now. Noted on the promises.